# What will be the output of the program if the array begins 1200 in memory?

Tags: c

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 main()
 {
    int arr[]={2, 3, 4, 1, 6};
    printf("%u, %u, %u\n", arr, &arr[0], &arr);
    return 0;
 }
```

Its Output is:-
1200 1200 1200
I want to know how its answer is 1200?

I want to know how does it work??

Comment: Output could be literally anything, since you have Undefined Behaviour. Use `%p` for pointers in `printf`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [So you think you know pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232303/so-you-think-you-know-pointers)

Comment: @PaulR check the website http://www.studytonight.com/c/tests/3. Its showing answer 1200 1200 1200 that's why I wanna know how does it work?

Comment: @Sillent_Killerzz: given that example I suggest you avoid that site in future.

Comment: A lot of s... around the web...

Comment: @Sillent_Killerzz the first 5 questions on this site are garbage, the 6th question is the first which makes sense. The first is undefined behaviour, the answer of the second is "none of them", the answer of the third is "all miss a ; at the end", ...

Comment: @mch Thank you for the information. I was also a little bit confused why its answer is that? Why are these sites giving wrong knowledge?

Comment: @PaulR which is the best site to practice C programs? Can you help me?

Comment: I wish we had something like a Stack Overflow blacklist over crappy sites. This studytonight.com site is awful! That test is written by a clueless beginner with completely outdated C knowledge. I peeked at their tutorial too and it is outdated by 25 years or so. Stay clear from that site!

Comment: @Sillent_Killerzz: unfortunately there are a lot of bad sites out there - I suggest you get a good book instead - here is a [somewhat useful list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/253056).

Comment: @Lundin: yes, I just noticed a dubious book on there (Norton) - I don't know of a better list though ?

Comment: @PaulR can you refer me a best website rather than a book?

Comment: @Sillent_Killerzz: most tutorial web sites are garbage - you can try some of the beginner challenges at http://hackerank.com, or the [dailyprogrammer subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer), but if you're serious about learning to program then you'll need at least one good book.

Answer (score 1):

arr &arr[0] and &arr all give the address of the array.

But the address of an array is not necessarily an integer, so your printf causes undefined behaviour.

The correct way would be: `printf("%p\n",(void *)arr);`. The actual output depends on your implementation and is most likely meaningless to you for any purpose for C programming.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` gives the base address of array (starting memory address of `arr`)

`&arr[0]` gives the address of first element in `arr` which is `1200.`

`&arr` is the address of the array itself (`int arr[]={2, 3, 4, 1, 6};`), so if you do `&arr+1` it will points to memory just past the end of the entirety of your array (`1200+sizeof(int)*5`).